# glob() to exclude sub-directories

Tags: python, linux, logging, glob

So I'm working on a script which will go through a bunch of log files looking for strings and server names.

In my testing I was using `glob()` to create a list of files to troll through.

However, to improve my testing I have copied a log directory from a live system (11gb!) - and things aren't as smooth as they were before.. it looks like glob treats the sub-directories as files, and as such the `readlines()` is struggling to read them.

I don't care about files in the sub-directories, I just want to scan through the files in the native directory.

I think I can use `os.walk()` to achieve this, with something like:

```
logs = next(os.walk('var/opt/server/log/current'))[2]
```

As opposed to:

```
logs = glob('/var/opt/server/log/current/*')
```

Because I'm learning python, I want to make sure I learn things the correct way.. so am I correct in what I'm saying above? Or should I use `glob()` in a slightly different way to achieve this goal?

Comment: The more I play around with it, the more I realize that `next()` is not the correct tool for the job here as it will raise `StopIteration` when it reaches the end of the list. I suppose I could use `try:` and `except:` for `StopIteration`, but it seems messy. I've read that `for*()` will automatically except `StopIteration` so maybe a for loop through the directory listing would be better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use glob and filter out all the dirs:

```
logs = [log for log in glob('/var/opt/server/log/current/*') if not os.path.isdir(log)]
```

Comment: That's great, thanks. That seems to work fine. Although testing is a slow process when it's going through every line in 11gb of log files! haha. - I'm sure I fully understand `log for log in` I get that `for log in ....` would be a loop for everything in the glob statement, but what is the first `log` bit doing? Does it store each iteration of `for log in glob()` as `log`?

Comment: @jonny That construction is called a list comprehension, or list comp for short. You can read about it in the official tutorial and there's more info in the main docs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the recursive argument to control how deep glob goes down. If you set `recursive=False` it will only match files in the current directory

Looks like this:

```py
logs = glob('/var/opt/server/log/current/*', recursive=False)
```